# How to reset pyenv after update to OSX Monterey?

Tags: macos, pyenv, reinstall

So, I've recently updated to OSX 12 Monterey and I'm having an issue with my pyenv setup. Actually, I've had all sorts of issues with the Homebrew installed apps, but how do I reset up the pyenv? I'm new to python but I know it's notorious for crazy setups so I resisted the urge to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

So, if this happens to anyone else, here's a [good article](https://ruddra.com/fix-python-after-brew-upgrade/) that points to what solved this for me, which was re-adding the environment variables

Comment: Thank you. This finally helped me resolve "pyenv pip command not found" on montery. Specifically I did: "pyenv global 3.9.13"